# How to use methods from different classes in react-native

Tags: java, react-native

I wanted to clean up my code by splitting out my methods over different classes, however since react native requires you to extend ReactContextBaseJavaModule I cant get it to work. Im working on a firebase messaging project, but that is irrelevant for the problem (i think)

Ive tried to use the standard ClassBName classB = new ClassBName(); in my ClassA, but it required ReactContext. I tried not extending reactcontext but it doesnt work either. Putting the declaration inside the constructor and using the passed on reactContext didnt do the trick either.

This is from my primary class:

```java
public class FirebaseMessageBase extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    FirebaseCreateMessage CreateMessage;
    FirebaseListMessageNames listMessageNames;
    FirebaseGetMessage getMessage;

    public FirebaseMessageBase(@Nonnull ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        CreateMessage = new FirebaseCreateMessage(reactContext);
        listMessageNames = new FirebaseListMessageNames(reactContext);
        getMessage = new FirebaseGetMessage(reactContext);
    }

    //rest of the class
}
```

And this is one of my secondary classes.

```java
public class FirebaseCreateMessage extends FirebaseMessageBase {

    public FirebaseCreateMessage(@Nonnull ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
    }
    //rest of class including the method
}
```

Error message:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context

Comment: you can try change `extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule`

Comment: Yeah but change it into what?

Comment: You can try to solve this problem using the interface.

Comment: How would I do that? since interfaces can only be abstract